Cannot trap SIGINT and SIGTERM when using "sleep infinity"
My example code:
#!/bin/bash

LOGFILE="/tmp/example.log"

cleanup_function() {
    echo "Script interrupted by SIGINT, cleaning up..." >> $LOGFILE
    exit 0
}

shutdown_function() {
    echo "Script terminated by SIGTERM, shutting down..."
    exit 0
}

# Traps to handle SIGINT and SIGTERM
trap 'cleanup_function' SIGINT
trap 'shutdown_function' SIGTERM

echo "Script running. It waits for SIGINT or SIGTERM..." >> $LOGFILE
sleep inf

Saved as testtrap.sh
In a terminal:
$ ./testtrap.sh

In another terminal:
$ ps -A | grep testtrap.sh
  28923 pts/2    00:00:00 testtrap.sh
$ kill -s SIGINT 28923
$ kill -s SIGTERM 28923
$ ps -A | grep testtrap.sh
  28923 pts/2    00:00:00 testtrap.sh

SIGINT and SIGTERM are not trapped e testtrap.sh is not killed by them. What's wrong?

script waits for sleep, no?

Try kill -s SIGINT -28923

From https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html :

When a signal for which a trap has been set is received while the shell is waiting for the completion of a utility executing a foreground command, the trap associated with that signal shall not be executed until after the foreground command has completed.

Your shell is executing sleep inf. The trap will not be executed until sleep inf finishes. You send the signal only to bash process, not to sleep.
There should be the similar documentation in bash manual and also check man bash.

Thank you very much. You have pointed me in the right direction and I have added this answer to better clarify:: https://stackoverflow.com/a/78433914/1277576

KamilCuk's answer is correct: https://stackoverflow.com/a/78432970/1277576
The same documentation linked in that answer says this:

When the shell is waiting, by means of the wait utility, for
asynchronous commands to complete, the reception of a signal for which
a trap has been set shall cause the wait utility to return immediately
with an exit status >128, immediately after which the trap associated
with that signal shall be taken.

So, the solution is to replace sleep inf with:
sleep inf &
wait $!  # Waits for the completion of the sleep command executed in the background

I did some testing and now the traps work both when the script is run in the foreground with ./testtrap.sh and when I run it in the background by starting it with ./testtrap.sh &.
